# Graph Client failing to initialize

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, angular6, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to set up an Angular application that grabs Outlook calendar data, however whenever I try to init the graph client I get an error that it is undefined.

```
function getUserEvents(callback) {
  getAccessToken(function(accessToken) {
    if (accessToken) {
      // Create a graph client
      console.log('trying to make client');
      const client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
        authProvider : (done) => {
          done(null, accessToken);
        }
      });
```

My accessToken function is working fine, it just gets to the client init line and I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: "_microsoft_microsoft_graph_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a is undefined"
```

This confuses me because I have the graph client imported into my project, but for some reason the imported module is still undefined?

EDIT: My import statement:

```
import MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';
```

Comment: I have pinged our dev who owns this library to take a look when he gets in.

Comment: @nichow can you share me the import statement and the webpack version that you are using.?

Answer (score 2):

[@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/src/index.ts) doesn't have a default export so importing defaults `import MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'` will not work.

Try namespace/named importing like

`import * as MicrosoftGraph from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";`